# Is it possible to downgrade the display on my Dell XPS 13?

Tags: laptop, display, lcd, xps

I want to know if it is possible to take a Dell XPS 13 9350(or Dell XPS 13 9360) with i7 processor and 16GB RAM, and replace the display that comes with it, a QHD display with touch screen, with a FHD no-touch display.

Dell does not ship this variation of the XPS 13 so I want to know if doing this is something on the same difficulty level of replacing a broken display and maybe updating the BIOS, or if this is something impossible to do because of hardware incompatibility.